# How to use a custom crypto algorithm in ipsec?

Tags: linux, kernel, ipsec

I wrote a custom algorithm using the kernel crypto API (by modifying the existing SHA1 and DES algorithms), compiled and added the .KO object to kernel.

How can I use my algorithm in `ipsec` and other app that use cryptographic communication?

Comment: Each application has its own way of specifying which algorithms to use. So… which IPsec stack are you using?

Comment: i use KLIPS stack.

Comment: First Law of Cryptography:  Thou shall not roll your own crypto. Sorry, someone had to say it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use homebrewed crypto for anything remotely serious. The risk is just too great.

Answer (score 0):

[Strongswan](http://www.strongswan.org/) is generally considered to be the IPSec suite of choice (for VPNs) on Linux. Is that what you are looking for?